# Отправка большого количества писем

Tags: php, sendmail

*Приветствую.*

Необходимо реализовать ежедневную рассылку ~100K писем.

1. Какие могут возникнуть проблемы?
2. Какова вероятность того, что письма попадут в спам?
3. Выдержит ли почтовый сервер?

Отправка через `mail()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужно немного подумать... Вот, например, PHP-сценарий может выполняться после обновления страницы на дольше установленного лимита выполнения в апаче. Из этого следует,
что 100K писем точно не удастся отослать одним обновлением. Для этого надо создать приблизительно такой скрипт:

1. Разбить список адресов на более мелкие списки и отсылать каждый такой список каждый раз, после обновления страницы.
2. Отсылка->обновление->Отсылка->обновление...и так далее

Comment: Какова вероятность попадания писем в спам?

Comment: Фильтр спама работает по принципу блокирования IP, с которого рассылаются письма. Так как PHP - серверный язык, то IP будет одним.
Для того, чтобы ваш IP на посчитали за спамерский, то проводить рассылку писем лучше раз в 48 или даже 72 часа.

Comment: Последнее предложение вероятно написано не правильно.

Comment: Почему же? Спам-фильтры блокируют рассылку по IP.

Comment: Как можно реализовать рассылку с разных IP?

Comment: Об этом нужно точно не публично разговаривать =)

Comment: skype uweb_ws

Comment: Найдено 51 совпадение...

Comment: Только я один думаю что делать это на PHP - извращение?..